# php redirection that won't redirect

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, http-redirect

I'm making a redirection thanks to PHP but it doesn't redirect at all (but make everithing else that redirecting).

here's the code that I've implemented:

```
<?php 
session_start();    // pour pouvoir récupérer /creer desvariables de session

try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=youf', 'root', 'root');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

$redirection="command.php";
if (!isset($_SESSION['Login'])){ header('Location: connect.php'); } // Si pas de sessionactives, redirect
    if (!isset($_SESSION['CommandId'])){
        $long = strlen($_SESSION['Login']);
        $table = $_SESSION['Login'][$long-2].$_SESSION['Login'][$long-1];
        $zone = $_SESSION['Login'][$long-4].$_SESSION['Login'][$long-3];
        $createCommand="INSERT INTO `youfood`.`command` (`Number`, `Date`, `isPaid`, `Table`, `Zone`, `Server`, `State`) VALUES (NULL, current_date, '0', '".$table."', '".$zone."', '".$_SESSION['NumberEmployee']."', '5');";
        $bdd->query($createCommand);

        $sqlCommandNumber=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM  `command` WHERE  `Table` =".$table." AND  `Zone` =".$zone." AND  `State` =0 LIMIT 0 , 1");
        $commandNumber="";
        while ($data=$sqlCommandNumber->fetch()){
            $commandNumber = $data['Number'];
        }
        $_SESSION['CommandId'] = $commandNumber ;
        header('Location: actionValidateCommand.php');
        $redirection="actionValidatedCommand.php";
    } else {
        foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value ) {
            if($value != 0){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO  `youfood`.`commanddishe` (`Number` ,`command` ,`Dishe` ,`Quantity`)VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['CommandId']."', '".$key."', '".$value."')";
                $bdd->query($sql);
                $messagee = $messagee."<br />".$sql."<br />";
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key] = 0 ;
            }
        }
    header('Location: command.php');
    $redirection="command.php";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
```

And when I inspect the html result of the page that doesn't redirect, I see a space before the  tag. I don't know where the space is made and I know that it's the mistake!

Thanks to help me :-)

Comment: try to use: header('Location: path/here'); exit;

Comment: what is the purpose of $redirect= ...? Just ensure there is nothing output to browser at aol before header() will be called.

Comment: Space before which tag? You probably send output before headers. Check with `headers_sent` and `headers_list`.

Answer (score 2):

You are outputting things before the header is initiated.

I.e.: `$messagee = $messagee."<br />".$sql."<br />";`

In order for the redirect to work properly, you should avoid outputting ANYTHING before the header line.

Also try this: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your file. See if it returns an error or warning.

Comment: Correct answer, wrong rationale ;-) The needless white-space comes from the line break between `?>` and `<!DOCTYPE html>` and can't have anything to do with the redirect-failure, since the header would be sent before the white-space will get echoed…

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. This means that the correct thing to do would just putting a exit(); statement after each header initiation.

Comment: The line `$messagee = $messagee."<br />".$sql."<br />";` isn't actually outputting anything. Actually the above code has nothing to output at all.

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace you see is probably the UTF **Byte Order Mark** (BOM).
Use some programs like Notepad++ or even a hex editor to remove it.
Here is a reference: http://www.sunfinedata.com/tips/remove-bom-from-utf-8-files/

If there is a BOM, PHP tells Apache to send response header and after that no extra headers can be set.

If you enable display_errors in php.ini, you will see something like this:

**Warning:** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /blah/blah.php:1) in **/blah/blah.php** on line **1**

`session_start()` will also generates an error.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

P.S. I don't know why some people will downvote the possibly correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Always drop you output before sending headers:

```
// at the beginning of your script
ob_start();

// clean output before sending headers
ob_clean();
header( /* … */ );
```

The reason for the header to not get executed maybe resides in the first `if`-construct. Have you checked, that the condition is/can be true at any point?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find a space before the opening `<?php` tag, either in the php file in question or an included file, which doesn't seem to be the case here. Or after the closing `?>`